# nested forms with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I have a post model with

```
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :views, :allow_destroy => :true,
      :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| v.blank? } }
```

And a views model with

```
    belongs_to :post, inverse_of: :views
```

In posts/_forms.html.erb

```
    <%= post_form.fields_for :views do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'view_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to_add_fields "Add new View", post_form, :views %>
```

In posts/_view_fields.html.erb

```
    <fieldset>
    <%= f.label :name, "View name:" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
    </fieldset>
```

Now in my rspec, I want to fill the f.text_field with some value.

Tried the following:

```
  fill_in 'post_views_first_name', with: "I support"
  fill_in 'post_view_name', with: "I support"
  fill_in 'post_views_name', with: "I support"
```

None of the them work. How do I call fill_in on this field?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a the capybara screenshot gem (Which I highly suggest!). I have a nested form with projects belonging to users. And it accepts

`fill_in 'user_projects_attributes_0_name', with: "Name"`

So for you, I suggest grabbing the gem for sure. But also try this:

`fill_in 'post_views_attributes_0_first_name', with: "I support"`

Answer (score 0):

While @Stephen's answer is on the right track, namely that you need to specify the `id` attribute value of the input field, and it's gonna have some number in it, it does not cover the case when a new nested resource is being added and it does not yet have a nice id. It will tend to get some generated number, for example the HTML may come out like this:

```html
<div class="post_views_content>
  <textarea class="text required" name="post[views_attributes][1711119995807][content]" id="post_views_attributes_1711119995807_name"></textarea>
```

In this case you can still try to find the input element and obtain its `id` to pass into `fill_in` helper:

```rb
input_id = find(".post_views_content textarea")["id"]
fill_in input_id, with: "I support"
```